# How resolve the OutOfMemory Exception while printing c# WPF

Tags: c#, wpf

In my applications, i need to print a control which have more number of lines with ScrollViewer. I have tried to convert by using Bitmap and break into pages.

https://www.codeproject.com/Articles/339416/Printing-large-WPF-UserControls

Where i got the Out of Memory Exception.

Please find my codes in the below.

```
    public void PrintPages(FrameworkElement element, ScrollViewer Viewer)
    {
        PrintDialog dlg = new PrintDialog();
        FrameworkElement printable = element;
        double tempheight = printable.ActualHeight;
        double tempwidth = printable.ActualWidth;
        Window window = Window.GetWindow(printable);
        System.Windows.Point loction = VisualUtils.GetPointRelativeTo(printable, window);
        double actualheight = Viewer.ExtentHeight;
        double actualwidth = Viewer.ExtentWidth;
        System.Drawing.Bitmap bmp = null;

        if (dlg != null && printable != null)
        {
            Mouse.OverrideCursor = Cursors.Wait;

            System.Printing.PrintCapabilities capabilities =
                dlg.PrintQueue.GetPrintCapabilities(dlg.PrintTicket);
            dlg.PrintTicket.PageBorderless = System.Printing.PageBorderless.None;

            double dpiScale = dpiY / 96.0;
            FixedDocument document = new FixedDocument();




          try
          {
              //Sets width and waits for changes to settle.
              printable.Width = capabilities.PageImageableArea.ExtentWidth;
              printable.UpdateLayout();

              //Recomputes the desired height.
              printable.Measure(new Size(
                  actualwidth,
                  actualheight));

              printable.Height = actualheight;
              printable.Width = actualwidth;
              printable.UpdateLayout();


              //Sets the new desired size.
              Size size = new Size(
                  actualwidth,
                  actualheight);

              //Measures and arranges to the desired size.
              printable.Measure(size);
              printable.Arrange(new Rect(size));

              //  dlg.PrintVisual(printable, "print");

              //Converts GUI to bitmap at 300 DPI
              RenderTargetBitmap bmpTarget = new RenderTargetBitmap(
                  (int)(capabilities.PageImageableArea.ExtentWidth * dpiScale),
                  (int)(printable.ActualHeight * dpiScale),
                  dpiX, dpiY, PixelFormats.Pbgra32);
              bmpTarget.Render(printable);

              //Converts RenderTargetBitmap to bitmap.
              PngBitmapEncoder png = new PngBitmapEncoder();
              png.Frames.Add(BitmapFrame.Create(bmpTarget));

              using (MemoryStream memStream = new MemoryStream())
              {
                  png.Save(memStream);
                  bmp = new System.Drawing.Bitmap(memStream);
                  png = null;
              }

              using (bmp)
              {
                  document.DocumentPaginator.PageSize =
                      new Size(dlg.PrintableAreaWidth, dlg.PrintableAreaHeight);

                  //Breaks bitmap to fit across pages.
                  int pageBreak = 0;
                  int lastPageBreak = 0;
                  int pageHeight = (int)
                      (capabilities.PageImageableArea.ExtentHeight * dpiScale);

                  //Adds each full page.
                  while (pageBreak < bmp.Height - pageHeight)
                  {
                      pageBreak += pageHeight;

                      // if (pageBreak < 18000)
                      //Finds a page breakpoint from bottom, up.
                      pageBreak = FindRowBreakpoint(bmp, lastPageBreak, pageBreak);
                      //else
                      //    break;
                      //Adds the image segment to its own page.
                      PageContent pageContent = GeneratePageContent(
                          bmp, lastPageBreak, pageBreak,
                          document.DocumentPaginator.PageSize.Width,
                          document.DocumentPaginator.PageSize.Height,
                          capabilities);

                      document.Pages.Add(pageContent);
                      lastPageBreak = pageBreak;
                  }


                  //Adds remaining page contents.
                  PageContent lastPageContent = GeneratePageContent(
                      bmp, lastPageBreak,
                      bmp.Height, document.DocumentPaginator.PageSize.Width,
                      document.DocumentPaginator.PageSize.Height, capabilities);

                  document.Pages.Add(lastPageContent);
              }
          }
          catch (Exception e)
          {
              MessageBox.Show(e.Message);
          }

          //Drops visual size adjustments.
          finally
          {
              //Unsets width and waits for changes to settle.
              printable.Width = double.NaN;
              printable.UpdateLayout();

              printable.LayoutTransform = new ScaleTransform(1, 1);

              //Recomputes the desired height.
              Size size = new Size(
                  capabilities.PageImageableArea.ExtentWidth,
                  capabilities.PageImageableArea.ExtentHeight);

              //Measures and arranges to the desired size.
              printable.Measure(size);
              printable.Arrange(new Rect(new Point(
                  capabilities.PageImageableArea.OriginWidth,
                  capabilities.PageImageableArea.OriginHeight), size));

              Mouse.OverrideCursor = null;
          }

            dlg.PrintDocument(document.DocumentPaginator, "Print Document Name");

            printable.Height = tempheight;
            printable.Width = tempwidth;
            printable.UpdateLayout();
            printable.Measure(new System.Windows.Size(tempwidth, tempheight));
            printable.Arrange(new Rect(loction, new System.Windows.Size(tempwidth, tempheight)));
        }
    }


    private static int FindRowBreakpoint(
        System.Drawing.Bitmap bmp,
        int topLine,
        int bottomLine)
    {
        //Any computed deviation above the threshold
        //is considered too detailed to break on.
        double deviationThreshold = 1627500;



        //Locks to read data.
        System.Drawing.Imaging.BitmapData bmpData = bmp.LockBits(
            new System.Drawing.Rectangle(0, 0, bmp.Width, bmp.Height),
            System.Drawing.Imaging.ImageLockMode.ReadOnly, bmp.PixelFormat);

        //Sets the initial row and position.
        int stride = bmpData.Stride;
        IntPtr topLeftPixel = bmpData.Scan0;
        // byte* p = (byte*)(void*)topLeftPixel;

        //Iterates from bottom to top to find a breakable row.
        for (int i = bottomLine; i > topLine; i--)
        {
            int count = 0;
            double total = 0;
            double totalVariance = 0;

            //Iterates through each consecutive pixel in the given row.
            for (int column = 0; column < bmp.Width; column++)
            {
                count++;
            }

            //Breaks on this line if possible.
            double standardDeviation = Math.Sqrt(totalVariance / count);
            if (Math.Sqrt(totalVariance / count) < deviationThreshold)
            {
                bmp.UnlockBits(bmpData);
                return i;
            }
        }

        //Breaks on the last line given if no break row is found.
        bmp.UnlockBits(bmpData);
        return bottomLine;
    }


    private static PageContent GeneratePageContent(
        System.Drawing.Bitmap bmp,
        int top,
        int bottom,
        double pageWidth,
        double PageHeight,
        System.Printing.PrintCapabilities capabilities)
    {
        Image pageImage;
        BitmapSource bmpSource;

        //Creates a page with a specific width/height.
        FixedPage printPage = new FixedPage();
        printPage.Width = pageWidth;
        printPage.Height = PageHeight;

        //Cuts the given image at a reasonable boundary.
        int newImageHeight = bottom - top;

        //Creates a clone of the image.
        using (System.Drawing.Bitmap bmpCut =
            bmp.Clone(new System.Drawing.Rectangle(0, top, bmp.Width, newImageHeight),
            bmp.PixelFormat))
        {
            //Prepares the bitmap source.
            pageImage = new Image();
            bmpSource =
                System.Windows.Interop.Imaging.CreateBitmapSourceFromHBitmap(
                    bmpCut.GetHbitmap(),
                    IntPtr.Zero,
                    Int32Rect.Empty,
                    BitmapSizeOptions.FromWidthAndHeight(bmpCut.Width, bmpCut.Height));
        }

        //Adds the bitmap to the page.
        pageImage.Source = bmpSource;
        pageImage.VerticalAlignment = VerticalAlignment.Top;
        printPage.Children.Add(pageImage);

        PageContent pageContent = new PageContent();
        ((System.Windows.Markup.IAddChild)pageContent).AddChild(printPage);

        //Adds a margin.
        printPage.Margin = new Thickness(
            horizontalBorder, verticalBorder,
            horizontalBorder, verticalBorder);

        FixedPage.SetLeft(pageImage, capabilities.PageImageableArea.OriginWidth);
        FixedPage.SetTop(pageImage, capabilities.PageImageableArea.OriginHeight);

        //Adjusts for the margins and to fit the page.
        pageImage.Width = capabilities.PageImageableArea.ExtentWidth - horizontalBorder * 2;
        pageImage.Height = capabilities.PageImageableArea.ExtentHeight - verticalBorder * 2;
        return pageContent;
    }
```

[image: [Exception]]

Can any one please suggest how can i proceed on this further?

Comment: Could you also please "Copy exception detail.." and include?

Comment: {The function evaluation was disabled because of an out of memory exception.} this is the exception i am facing